# Next.js getStaticProps runs on every request in production

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, strapi

`getStaticProps` runs on every request in prod. (locally as well when start with next build && next start). `NODE_END` is set  to `production`. `fallback` is set to `false`.

no re-validation.

next.js 12.3.4v

not sure what may cause this...